# Phonegap build - development environment - Using the WinPhone environment to build android apps with build service

Tags: android, ide, cordova, windows-phone-7

Say I'm a windows dev, familiar with Visual Studio and with a need of developing an Andriod app. I looked at both the andriod and wp7 getting started guides, but found the windows phone version http://phonegap.com/start/#wp guide much simpler than the Android version (of course, as a windows dev I have already everything installed).

Then comes my question:

Could I develop my app using the Windows Phone environment, and then use the PhoneGap Build services to get the Android version build?

In case, what should I upload to the build service?

Sorry if I got this all wrong, and thanks for any help!

Larsi

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea of phonegap is to develop a multi platform app writing the code once.

So the answer is yes, you should be able to build the app for wp, and then re-use your code for all the other platforms, only if you onlyuse the phonegap API and do all your programming in JS, HTML and CSS.

About what you should upload, I haven't doned it myself, but I think that It would have to be all the JS, HTML and CSS from your app. In android all is located on a folder called "assets".

Good Luck!